# Varnish Cache v4: Incorrect Backend Health Check Response

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I've setup Varnish Cache (4) in front of my CMS to help cache requests. In the event that my CMS goes down, I'd like to deliver cached items for a set grace period. I've followed many examples provided online but am running into an issue where Varnish doesn't recognize that my backend is down. When I manually shutdown the CMS the `std.health(req.backend_hint))` continues to return true and attempts to retrieve an item from the backend, which then returns a 503 response.

Question: Am I incorrectly assuming `std.health(req.backend_hint))` will recognize that my CMS is down?

Here is the VCL script I've been using to test:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # Initial State
  set req.http.grace = "none";
  set req.http.x-host = req.http.host;
  set req.http.x-url = req.url;

  return(hash);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.ttl = 10s;
    set beresp.grace = 1h;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Copy grace to resp so we can tell from client
    set resp.http.grace = req.http.grace;

    # Add debugging headers to cache requests
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    }
    else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # normal hit
        return (deliver);
    }
    # We have no fresh content, lets look at the cache
    elsif (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        # Backend is healthy. Limit age to 10s.
        if (obj.ttl + 10s > 0s) {
            set req.http.grace = "normal(limited)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # No candidate for grace. Fetch a fresh object.
            return(fetch);
        }
    } else {
        # backend is sick - use full grace
        if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
            set req.http.grace = "full";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # no graced object.
            return (fetch);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, when I shutdown the CMS the `std.healthy(req.backend_hint))` still reports the backend as healthy and never jumps to the final else statement.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly use `std.healthy` you of course need to configure backend probes. So at the top of your VCL file you would first configure a probe:

```cpp
probe site_probe {
    .request =
        "HEAD / HTTP/1.1"
        "Host: example.com"
        "Connection: close";
        .interval  = 5s; # check the health of each backend every 5 seconds
        .timeout   = 3s;  # timing out after 1 second by default.
        .window    = 5;  # If 3 out of the last 5 polls succeeded the backend is considered healthy, otherwise it will be marked as sick
        .threshold = 3;
 }
```

Make sure to replace `example.com` with your main website domain. It is important to put (or omit) the `www.` prefix so that the probe will not get redirect and marked as failed.

And of course your backend definition should be configured to use the defined probe:

```cpp
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .probe = site_probe;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great but also introduced a new issue. When I bring my backend down it correctly serves the object in grace. However, when I bring my backend back up again it doesn't recognize it has returned to health. When the grace period has expired the `return(fetch)` is called and a 503 backend error is returned. For some reason it seems to loose connection?

Comment: @DavidBeaudway have a look at results from ```varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health``` - do you see Varnish detecting backend as healthy when it's not down?

Comment: It reports healthy initially, then changes to sick as I bring it down, but never flips back to healthy when I bring it back up. I have Varnish and the CMS deployed in OpenShift and I'm wondering if this is causing some issue. My backend default settings are slightly different where `.host = "mesh";`. The "mesh" value is a variable within OpenShift. When the backend container is brought back up the "mesh" value might be different and Varnish is still looking to the old host location -- that's my best guess?

Comment: Most likely. As to my knowledge Varnish resolves whatever you have in ```.host``` of the ```backend``` definitions, so it makes little sense to put there anything but an IP address. Anyway, can you specify the output from backend health checks? (earlier command). It contains quite some useful information to help you understand why probe fails.

Comment: The Backend_health logs return the following and continue to report "Still sick":

`0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4--X--- 3 3 5 0.000000 0.030177`
`0 Backend_health - default Went sick ------- 2 3 5 0.000000 0.030177`
`0 Backend_health - default Still sick ------- 1 3 5 0.000000 0.030177 `

After further de-bugging I've confirmed that when I turn the backend back on it comes up on a different IP address. Somehow I'll need Varnish to attempt re-assigning the backend host location when it gets sick.

Comment: @DavidBeaudway [this](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/varnish-backends-in-the-cloud) is the best solution I've found on the matter. You'd basically have a separate backend defined for each IP and script your way into generating those definitions.